# "The document could not be saved as" Cocoa error

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I've written a note application in Cocoa with Objective-C, it launches but when I save the file it shows me this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgTwD.jpg. And the console, even if the constraints are ok, the default ones:

```
2017-04-17 14:21:42.095495+0300 Notes[4650:343877] Attempting to access document's contents, but none found!
2017-04-17 14:21:42.152172+0300 Notes[4650:343877] [Layout] Detected missing constraints for <NSTextField: 0x10027aaf0>.  It cannot be placed because there are not enough constraints to fully define the size and origin. Add the missing constraints, or set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=YES and constraints will be generated for you. If this view is laid out manually on macOS 10.12 and later, you may choose to not call [super layout] from your override. Set a breakpoint on DETECTED_MISSING_CONSTRAINTS to debug. This error will only be logged once.
```

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint on DETECTED_MISSING_CONSTRAINTS to debug?

Comment: No, but I don't think that the document not saving is due to the constraints.

Comment: What code is the "Attempting to access document's contents, but none found!" message coming from?

Comment: @PhillipMills, I don't know, the message pops up when I try to save the document.

Comment: I asked because I don't think it's an Apple message.  Are you using any 3rd-party code or libraries for saving?

Comment: No, it's a document based application, it's an Apple message. Apparently, this line `[[self documentFileWrapper] addRegularFileWithContents:textRTFData preferredFilename:@"Text.rtf"];` causes the problem, where `textRTFData = [[self text] dataFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, [[self text] length]) documentAttributes: @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSRTFTextDocumentType} error:&error];
` and `text` is a NSAttributedString.

Comment: It would help us to help you if you post your code in the question.